# Xamarin custom window text

Tags: android, xamarin, textbox, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin and I was wondering if it's possible to present text (with on click); something like the screenshot.

[image: Screen]

I've seen few apps using it (ignore the ActionBar design).

Thank you.

Comment: With "to present a text with onclick" you mean show something like a message on the screen?

Comment: Hi, 
I was under assumption that this was some kind of a menu drop down, but I was wrong...
I have used ViewStates instead on the layer, and it works really well. After bit of styling the whole Activity looks like I wanted to on the screenshot

Comment: I can't get what is your question. What do you want to show "OnClick" ?

Comment: Hi, 
I was under assumption that this was some kind of a menu drop down, but I was wrong...
I have used ViewStates  on the layer, and it works really well. After bit of styling the whole Activity looks like I wanted to on the screenshot.
I'm quite impressed that the workaround was so simple...
<button 1 with on/off LayoutStates>
<Layout 1>
<button 2with on/off LayoutStates>
<Layout 2>
Sorry... I'm trying to get used to this forum...
I should be good now :)
Thank you.